# ABAP LOOP into work area with no result leave function

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I'm working on function module and I'm in trouble with my loop statement. My problem is, when nothing is found in this loop (this case needs to be handled) the program ends directly to `endfunction` and my else condition on bottom is not triggered.

Can someone explain me how to run my code even if no result is found in my loop? I'm hard stuck.

Thanks :)

```
  LOOP AT it_p0015 INTO ls_p0015 WHERE
  subty = iv_sty      AND
  betrg = iv_amount   AND
  endda = iv_end_date AND
  begda = iv_start_date.
        CALL FUNCTION 'ENQUEUE_EPPRELE'
      EXPORTING
        pernr          = iv_employeepernr "is_request-employeepernr
        infty          = '0015'
        subty          = iv_sty
      EXCEPTIONS
        foreign_lock   = 1
        system_failure = 2
        OTHERS         = 3.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      RETURN.
    ENDIF.

    CALL FUNCTION 'HR_INFOTYPE_OPERATION' " Delete IT0015
      EXPORTING
        infty         = ls_p0015-infty
        number        = ls_p0015-pernr
        subtype       = ls_p0015-subty
        validityend   = iv_end_date
        validitybegin = iv_start_date
        record        = ls_p0015
        operation     = 'DEL'
      IMPORTING
        return        = ls_return.

    IF ls_return IS NOT INITIAL.
      APPEND ls_return TO et_message.
    ELSE.
      ls_return-type = 'S'.
      ls_return-message = 'Infotype 0015 advance payment deduction deleted.'(010).
      APPEND ls_return TO et_message.
    ENDIF.

    CALL FUNCTION 'DEQUEUE_EPPRELE'
      EXPORTING
        pernr = iv_employeepernr
        infty = '0015'
        subty = iv_sty.



  ELSE.
    ls_return-type = 'E'.
    ls_return-message = 'No records found in infotype 0015.'(036).
    APPEND ls_return TO et_message.
ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
  ENDIF.
ENDFUNCTION
```

Comment: I guess you want to return a message if none line matches the WHERE selection of the LOOP, so you can check `sy-subrc` after `ENDLOOP` because its value is `4` in that case (and `0` if at least one line was found). For more information, refer to the ABAP documentation for `LOOP AT`.

Comment: I tried to add a condition 'if sy-subrc <> 0' right after the loop, but the program triggered 'endfunction' without passing through the condition

Comment: You should then restructure your question with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can reproduce your case. You create a standalone program at your side with embedded data, make sure it reproduces the issue and that we can copy/paste/run/reproduce. I hope you understand.

Comment: The last `ELSE` in this code example doesn't appear to have a corresponding `IF`. Can you please revise your code to be actually syntactically correct?

Answer (score 0):

First, you could always see if sy-tabix has a value set, that's an indicator of the current line in the loop.
Personally, if you're struggling I would just set a variable in the loop that's set so you know if it ran or not.

i.e.

```
    lv_loop = 0.    
    LOOP AT it INTO ls WHERE.
      lv_loop = 1.
    ENDLOOP.
    IF lv_loop = 0. "code didn't run
      "handle case
    ENDIF.
```